# How can I build a VisualStudio Code project with full styling

Tags: html, css, web, visual-studio-code, build

[image]I am using Visual Studio Code to build a website but I cannot preview the site I am making. I tried building it and even adding extensions but I only get the unstyled HTML version without CSS. What are the possibilities to view my work as it is?

This is the HTML file

```
<html>

    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Title</title>
        <link href="login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play" rel="stylesheet">
    
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="signin">

            <form>

                <h2 style="color:white">Log In</h2>
               
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
               
                <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
               
                <a href=""><input type="button" value="Log In"></a><br><br>
               
                <div id="container">
                    <a href="#" style="margin-right: 0px; font-size: 13px; font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;">Reset password</a>
                    <a href="#" style="margin-right: 0px; font-size: 13px; font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;">Forgot password</a>    
                </div><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                
                Don't have an account?<a href="#">&nbsp;Sign Up</a>

            </form>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

This is the CSS file

```
body
{
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: url(IMG-6786.JPG);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch logn.html",
            "type": "firefox",
            "request": "launch",
            "reAttach": true,
            "file": "${workspaceFolder}/logn.html"
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch localhost",
            "type": "firefox",
            "request": "launch",
            "reAttach": true,
            "url": "http://localhost/logn.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "firefox",
            "request": "attach"
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch WebExtension",
            "type": "firefox",
            "request": "launch",
            "reAttach": true,
            "addonPath": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Maybe I can edit something in this launch.json file

Comment: What did  you use to view the HTML?

Comment: I right clicked and chose open in default browser

Comment: but I don't know how to open the entier folder as a whole (I am new to VS Code). I couldn't find anything useful on youtube

Comment: html5 demands **closing** of all tags `<xxx/>`. What are the locations of these files? Why do you have style stuff hard coded in your HTML file?

Comment: what happens if you use a simple webserver for static content. VSC seems to have a live server but I haven't used it, I use `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`